# Can a class method be called from an async pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Is it possible to call a method on an observable class via an async pipe?

I've tried the following, but I can't get it to work. So I was wondering if this is possible or could be done in a better way?

**app.component.html**

```
<p>Total Cost: {{ (orderState$ | async).TotalPrice() }}</p>
```

**order.state.ts**

```
export class OrderState {
    lineItems: OrderLineItem[];

    public TotalPrice(): number
    {
        // TODO: Calculate price of line items
        return 199;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of trying this?

Comment: Sure: http://plnkr.co/edit/KNUZvoXCLVeTGTrldPIa?p=preview. If you posted what you tried, and what the error is, preferrably as a complete minimal example, we could help. Otherwise, the answer to your question is "Yes", but I you really want to ask that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another observable if it is necessary. It will be better then set a variable inside `subscribe`.

```
export class OrderState {
  lineItems: OrderLineItem[];
  get totalPrice(): number {
    // TODO: Calculate price of line items
    return 199;
  }
}

export class TheComponent {
  orderState$: Observable<OrderState>;
  // Here
  totalPrice$: Observable<string>;

  constructor() {
    // And then after you know what the orderState is.
    this.totalPrice$ = this.orderState$.map(state => state.totalPrice);
  }
}

<p>Total Cost: {{totalPrice$ | async}}</p>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could do the trick.
Basically subscribe to the stream in the constructor and when data arrives calculate the price.

Also if you are going to unit test this will be easier than everything in the template.

**app.component.html**

```
<p>Total Cost: {{ totalPrice }}</p>
```

**order.state.ts**

```
export class OrderState {
  lineItems: OrderLineItem[];
  totalPrice: string = '';

  constructor() {
    orderState$.subscribe((value) => {
      this.totalPrice = this.CalculateTotalPrice(value);
    });
  }

  public CalculateTotalPrice(): number {
    // TODO: Calculate price of line items
    return 199;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. Here is how the [updateRenderer function](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d) looks like that is generated by the compiler:

```
function(_ck,_v) {
    ...
    var currVal_1 = jit_unwrapValue_7(_v,7,0,jit_nodeValue_8(_v,8).transform(_co.orderState$)).TotalPrice();
    _ck(_v,7,0,currVal_1);
  });
```

Let's see what it evaluates to. First this part:

```
jit_nodeValue_8(_v,8).transform(_co.orderState$)
```

The `transform` method subscribes to the `orderState$` observable and returns the instance of `OrderState`. Then this part:

```
jit_unwrapValue_7(...)
```

The `unwrapValue` function returns the instance as well:

```
export function unwrapValue(view: ViewData, nodeIdx: number, bindingIdx: number, value: any): any {
  if (value instanceof WrappedValue) {
      ....
  }
  return value;
}
```

So the result of evaluating the entire expression:

```
jit_unwrapValue_7(_v,7,0,jit_nodeValue_8(_v,8).transform(_co.orderState$))
```

is the instance of `OrderState` and so you can call any method on it:

```
jit_unwrapValue_7(...).TotalPrice();
```

Comment: Helo, @Maximus! Like your articles.. But why not simply create a new observable with `map` and also make getter instead of method? Why do this really difficult-to-read piece of code? :)

Comment: @LyubimovRoman, I don't know :). I'm just answering the question regarding Angular expression functionality support, that is what the author asked. It's an answer from the internals of the Angular perspective